# Rails3: Skipping callbacks from within a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mongoid

I have the following `after_save` callbacks defined in my model.

```
after_save :validate_image, :publish, :update_some_data, :send_notifications
```

Is it possible to skip rest of the `after_save` callbacks based on some condition in `validate_image`, so something like this -

```
def validate_image
  if image_not_valid
    # skip rest of the callbacks in the after_save chain
    destroy # destroy this record
  end
end
```

NOTE:- I am also destroying the record based on that condition and I have some "after_destroy" callbacks that need to be executed.

I am using Rails v3.2.6 with Mongoid v2.4.10, but I guess it wont make a difference if it was ActiveRecord.

Comment: I find that saving the same record again in a callback, triggers more callbacks, hence no good. Probably is the same problem with destroy. Is there a better way for you other than destroying (!) on what is a  save operation ?

Comment: How about moving `validate_image` to be a validation callback ?

Comment: We are using Carrierwave for image uploads, and in "validate_image" we validate if the image were really uploaded and is valid. My understanding is that Carrierwave uploads the image during after_save callback.

Comment: Yes, Carrierwave does upload in an after_save callback. Did you know that errors will rollback the transaction in an after_save ? In fact if the image wasn't really uploaded, Carrierwave should have issued an exception. If you are checking for something custom, you can raise your own error

Comment: Yea thats the strange part, (for some of the images) when we hit the uploaded image URL, s3 complains about the URL (access denied). Thats why as a fallback we are doing a check if the uploaded image path is really valid or not. We do this by doing a "head" check.

Comment: Ah, just noticed you are using Mongoid, hence transactions does not work. Anyway, sounds like a Carrierwave bug, or your S3 bucket/s not configured right, fix it there? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your before_save definition like this

```
after_save do
   validate_image
   unless image_not_valid
       publish 
       update_some_data 
       send_notifications
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With ActiveRecord:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks are cancelled

With Regular callbacks, only the before_* callbacks are stopped once one returns false

Comment: that's only true in `before_*` callbacks, not in after :)